# Data Extension Exclusion Doesn't Work - SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

It seems that there was a problem with the exclusion email list as 0 contacts were excluded from a transactional email sent to a large group. The sendable Data Extension used a contact ID as a primary key, while the excluded Data Extension had an email ID as the primary key. Despite both Data Extensions having email IDs, the exclusion list did not work as intended. The exclusion DE was created via a web form, and some individuals have opted out from receiving the following email. Their emails were collected via a form that populates the exclusion Data Extension. The Data Extensions are located in different folders (within the same BU in SFMC), which may have contributed to the issue. Can you please advise on how to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be:

Enter the emails to exclude on an auto-suppression configuration that references transactional send classifications (or a specific sender profile) instead of using a "data extension that you exclude".

Then use the send classification or sender profile for your sendout.

Obviously, the Send Classification will exclude these addresses globally for all transactional sendouts, the Sender Profile will only apply when used. Judge yourself what suits your requirement.

Auto suppression configurations then will *auto*-exclude matching *emails*  at send time (thats just how they work) - which eliminates all your mismatch potential with keys. (folders dont matter here)